# Resize PictureBox to match image size

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

How to resize the Picturebox so it can show the full image if the image size is less than monitor size ! I wrote a code which can not resize *(but still posting the code)*!

Code before loading image on a button click

```
Dim bmp As Bitmap
bmp = New Bitmap(path)
If bmp.Width < picBox.Image.Width Then picBox.Width = bmp.Width : If bmp.Height < picBox.Image.Height Then picBox.Height = bmp.Height
picBox.Invalidate() : picBox.Refresh()
'picBox.SetBounds(x,y,width,height)
```

The code does not resize the picturebox, it's just untouched  !

## Edit

The form has the picBox and a groupbox [dock enabled] control only.

```
bmp = New Bitmap(dlgOpen.FileName)
picBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Normal
Dim w As Integer = picBox.ClientSize.Width
Dim h As Integer = picBox.ClientSize.Height
If bmp.Width > w Then
            w = bmp.Width
End If
If bmp.Height > h Then
            h = bmp.Height
End If
If w > Me.Width - grpBox.Width Then
            w = Me.Width - grpBox.Width
End If
If h > grpBox.Height Then
            h = grpBox.Height
End If
picBox.ClientSize = New Size(w, h)
picBox.ImageLocation = dlgOpen.FileName
```

*This code does not re-sizes the picture box either* .

Comment: What about the code doesn't work?  Does it not resize at all?  Does it resize to the wrong size?  Too big?  Too small?  Does it not redraw properly after the resize?

Comment: @SteveDog Have updated the question !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Picture-box can be re-sized only **before loading the image**, there after it is read only and has no effect !

Answer (score 3):

In .NET, there's the `Public Enumeration PictureBoxSizeMode` that allows you to change how the PictureBox handles differently sized images:

- Normal
- StretchImage
- AutoSize
- CenterImage
- Zoom

You can set it for the current PictureBox via the `.SizeMode` property. `AutoSize` is probably what you are looking for. If it is larger than the window or frame, you will have to handle this in a `PictureBox.Resize` event to either resize the window or rescale the image.

So, it might be something like:

```
Dim bmp As Bitmap
bmp = New Bitmap(path)
picBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoResize
picBox.Image = bmp
```

Comment: What if the image is bigger than monitor size ?

Comment: **If bmp.Height < picBox.Height Then picBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize** does not changes the size

Comment: Try changing the setting before the new picture is loaded.

Comment: Ok, check out my latest edit. I didn't see where you were setting the PictureBox's image so I guessed some VB.NET code to set it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim bmp As New Bitmap(path)
PictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Normal
Dim w As Integer = PictureBox1.ClientSize.Width
Dim h As Integer = PictureBox1.ClientSize.Height
If bmp.Width > w Then
    w = bmp.Width
End If
If bmp.Height > h Then
    h = bmp.Height
End If
If w > maxWidth Then
    w = maxWidth
End If
If h > maxHeight Then
    h = maxHeight
End If
PictureBox1.ClientSize = New Size(w, h)
PictureBox1.Image = bmp
```

Comment: No effect, the form has only a dockable control [not the picture box]