# How to resize PictureBox and picture with ComboBox?

Tags: vb.net, combobox, visual-studio-2015, picturebox

Now i want do is select the size you want and the picture will change. i have did a example but it wont work.

here is my code

```
Private Sub cboxpizzasize_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cboxpizzasize.SelectedIndexChanged

    Select Case cboxselectclass.SelectedItem
        Case Is = "Personal - 4 slide"
            PictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
            PictureBox1.Size = New Size(134, 150)
        Case Is = "Regular - 6 slide"
            PictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
            PictureBox1.Size = New Size(174.2, 196.95)
        Case Is = "Large - 8 slide"
            PictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
            PictureBox1.Size = New Size(214.4, 242.4)
        Case Is = "Xtra Large - 12 slide"
            PictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
            PictureBox1.Size = New Size(268, 303)
    End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: "it wont work" is not an appropriate problem description.  Put `Option Strict On` at the top of the source file and fix the compile errors.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following:
[resizing](https://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/424869-autosize-image-pictureboxs-size)

Changing the SizeMode

Or have you read the following article: [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11724995/resize-picturebox-to-match-image-size)

> Picture-box can be re-sized only before loading the image, there after
>   it is read only and has no effect !

Comment: i can't go through the website

Comment: the links should be fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Set the SizeMode to StretchImage in the designer and then use the following code:

```
Private Sub cboxpizzasize_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cboxpizzasize.SelectedIndexChanged
    Select Case cboxpizzasize.SelectedIndex
        Case Is = 0
            PictureBox1.Size = New Size(134, 150)
        Case Is = 1
            PictureBox1.Size = New Size(174.2, 196.95)
        Case Is = 2
            PictureBox1.Size = New Size(214.4, 242.4)
        Case Is = 3
            PictureBox1.Size = New Size(268, 303)
    End Select
End Sub
```

(the ComboBox is called cboxpizzasize, the PictureBox is PictureBox1)